# Adding delay allows for if statement to execute properly

Tags: node.js, error-handling, async-await, try-catch, fetch-api

I have a handler which pings a server for data every few seconds. The only possible errors that could go wrong in this particular setup is the server/service going down, which would throw a ECONNREFUSED or ETIMEDOUT error. It will always recover within 2 minutes due to how the server is configured. The below code is the first part of the catch block if one of those two errors gets thrown, the part that makes no sense to me is that removing the timeout function will completely break the above if statement, but adding it allows everything to work as intended. This all resides inside an async function. Why can I not remove the timeout?

```
catch (error) {
        //In case there is an initial issue connecting to server, such as timeout.
        if (error.code == "ETIMEDOUT" || error.code == "ECONNREFUSED") {
            console.log(Date() + ": Cannot establish initial connection to ... server, reason is " + error.code + ".\nServer is sleeping and will retry in " + timeoutPeriod/1000 + " seconds.")
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeoutPeriod));
            console.log("Server done sleeping.");
            await getData();
        }
        //Needs this delay, otherwise wont catch above errors, for some reason(??????????).
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, pollPeriod));
              
        const data = await fetch('url', {
            method: 'get',
            headers: headers
        });
            
        const dataTEXT = await data.text();
        
        if (dataTEXT == "...")
            return null;
}
```

I have already tried removing the delay. It makes no sense as to why a delay would fix this, and it was only tried out of desperation.

edit: grammar and more code per user request.

Comment: This is to do with how JavaScript's runtime works. The timeout will push the execution off of the stack and into the queue, so it won't execute until the stack has cleared. The [Mozilla explanation of the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) should help you understand why it happens

Comment: what do you mean by "completely break" What is the expected behaviour? What is the observed behaviour? You obviously are executing some request which you don't show here. How do you do that? Where does `error` come from?

Comment: How can this all resied inside a "sync function"? You cannot use `await` inside a sync function ... Please add *all*  of the relevant code ...

Comment: @alexandercannon This is exactly the explanation I expected but could find the right answer too. Makes so much more sense now.

Comment: @derpirscher There is the entire catch statement, the try block is rather large and has no issues, it was also a typo in my OP, its async function now sync.